# Why Location services is Part of the Google Play service APK?

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, user-activity

I know Location Services is part of the Google Play services APK.

I have gone through the below link regarding the Location Update.

http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#PlayServices

I need the following things to be clarified to work the Google Play Services - Location Update or User Activity Recognition.

```
o   Why the Google play store needs to be installed to get the location update or user activity status. 
o   Why the required functionality is not integrated with android SDK.
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Get a job with Google and ask them. Nobody but Google can tell you definitively why they do things like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check this link, 
[Overview of Google Play Services](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html)

Q1. Why the Google play store needs to be installed to get the location update or user activity status.

> Google Play services APK contains the individual Google services and
>   runs as a background service in the Android OS. You interact with the
>   background service through the client library and the service carries
>   out the actions on your behalf.

Q2.Why the required functionality is not integrated with android SDK.

> Google Play services gives you the freedom to use the newest APIs for
>   popular Google services without worrying about device support. Updates
>   to Google Play services are distributed automatically by the Google
>   Play Store and new versions of the client library are delivered
>   through the Android SDK Manager. This makes it easy for you to focus
>   on what's important: your users' experience.

Comment: Ya thanks for your answer @Amolkumar. That is close to what i expected.